AWS Athena cloudwatch connector throws table not found in query editor
I've created a cloudwatch connector to query cloudwatch log group.
in the official doc mentions that there is an special view called "all_log_streams" which allows you to query through all the logs stream but the result of the query is a "table not found"
SELECT * 
FROM "lambda:athena_cloudwatch_connector"."/aws-glue/jobs/error"."all_log_streams" 
LIMIT 1


I certainly know that connector works because I tried to execute a query referencing the log stream and in deed I receive some logs in the query results

Is this "special view" created by itself or I missed to create it?
For reference: I've followed steps in official AWS docs related to use a cloudwatch connector which is on this url: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connectors-cloudwatch.html
Updates:
If I create add the connector as a data source then every log streams will behave as a table.

In the left panel in where you can see the list of tables (which is every log stream in the group) and the views it looks like in fact theres is a view (which I'm guessing is this "all_log_streams") but is just "loading" and is not showing the view information.


Did you Use the AWS Serverless Application Repository to deploy a data source connector - Amazon Athena?

Hi @JohnRotenstein,
Yes, I did.
The thing with that is that it creates every log stream as a separated table (which is not the desired behavior).
I want to execute queries that search the specific issue I have in all the log streams.
I'll upadte the post with the screenshot

does that all_logs_streams view show up in Athena in the left panel?  Just try doing select * from all_log_streams limit 100

Hi @TimMylott, It looks like a view does exist but is not finishing to "load" to render the views information. I'll update the post
